# How to disabled nvidia graphics card and start using intel hd 4600

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, intel, graphic-card, intel-graphics

I use UBuntu 14.04 LTS. I have cpu i4790k with hdgraphics 4600. How to disable my nvidia graphics card and start using intel hd 4600 ? Should I change something in bios or it is possible from the operating system ?

Comment: You just connect your monitor to the on-board video port.  There are also some knobs in the BIOS to configure which display to try first, but if you have a single monitor it should just work.