# How to swap integrated Intel graphics card to discrete AMD

Tags: kali-linux, graphics, intel-graphics, gpu

I am unable to change graphics card on Kali Linux 4.6.0, Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux with Gnome. Machine running is a HP Pavillion DV6.

I have tried:

- Reinstalling AMD drivers: does nothing even after multiple reboots
- Uncommenting grub config files: does nothing even after multiple reboots
- Using vgaswitcheroo: executes commands yet commands does absolutely nothing, integrated graphics remain + and Pwr while discreet is dynoff (see output 1 at bottom of page)
- Using DRI_PRIME: errors (see output 2)
- and many many more...

I am really running out of ideas and have gone through every post I could find on SE and other forums...

## Outputs

### 1. vgaswitcheroo

```
# sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:DIS: :DynOff:0000:01:00.0
1:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
```

### 2. editting conf

```
# DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo |grep renderer
Error: unable to open display
```

Related questions: [q1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202413/how-to-disabled-nvidia-graphics-card-and-start-using-intel-hd-4600), [q2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230564/switchable-graphics-intel-amd-venus-pro).

Comment: What is the output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"` ?